# How to append datafrarme columns in list?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to loop over multiple dataframes and do some some cleaning operations and finally append all the dataframe in single dataframe.

```
df1:
Id  Product
1   clothes
2   NaN
3   Shoes

df2:
Id  Product
4   gold
5   cosmetics
6   NaN

df3:
Id  Product
7   NaN
8   Elex
9   facecare
```

What i tried:

```
df_list = [df1,df2,df3]
Null_list = []
for df in df_list:
    df_null = df[df['Product'].isnull()]
    Null_list.append(df_null)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(Null_list,columns =['Id', 'Unmapped_Products']) ---error
```

what i need:

```
df_output:

Id  Products
2   NaN
6   NaN
7   Nan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat(Null_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Instead your solution is possible use list comprehension:

```
df = pd.concat([df[df['Product'].isnull()] for df in [df1,df2,df3]], ignore_index=True)
```